# Did Windows 7 eliminate temporary font usage with the font preview?

Tags: windows-7, fonts

In Windows XP, while a font was open in the font previewer you could also use it in other applications. It was kind of like a temporary install of the font. When you closed the previewer, the font would no longer be available. I used this feature often, as I have a lot of fonts I want to use only for a short period without having them clutter up my font list.

This doesn't appear to be working in Windows 7. Is this a feature that Microsoft eliminated?

Comment: I suspect that this may have to do with the underlying API calls, and as such an answer might be found on SO.

Answer (score 2):

It was probably a bug rather than a feature.

However, if you'd like temporary font loading in Windows 7, I suggest [AMP Font Viewer](http://www.ampsoft.net/utilities/FontViewer.php).  It's freeware, fairly lightweight, and does temporary font loading.  IIRC, you don't need to run as Administrator to have temp loading capability.